# Jasmine test case not resolving module above src folder

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

One of the components that I'm testing is importing a constants file which is located outside the `/src` folder. When I run the test, there is an error inside the `component.ts` file saying that the constants object is undefined. Below are the details. Any help will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

This is an error I'm getting when I run `ng test`.

**Error :**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROUTE_SERVICE_USER' of undefined
        at WelcomeComponent../src/app/welcome/welcome.component.ts.WelcomeComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/src/app/welcome/welcome.component.ts?:24:30)

**Folder Structure :**

[image]

**AppConstants.js :**

```
    const AppConstants = {

    HEADER_LANG: 'Content-Language',
    HEADER_LANG_LOWER: 'content-language',


    ROUT_WELCOME: '/welcome',
    ROUT_NEWUSER: '/newuser',

    ROUTE_SERVICE_USER: '/service/user/registered',
    };


    module.exports = AppConstants;
```

**Welcome.component.ts :**

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import AppConstants from '../../../common/AppConstants.js';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-welcome',
    templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css']
  })
  export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(AppConstants.ROUTE_SERVICE_USER);
    }

  }
```

**Welcome.component.spec.ts :**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';

describe('WelcomeComponent', () => {
  let component: WelcomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WelcomeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ WelcomeComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Move it under `src/app` so `webpack` can see it to include in the bundle. Or turn it into a `node` module and load it as a `dependency` via `package.json`

Comment: I can't move it inside `src/app` as It has other constants that are used by the modules inside `/server`.

Comment: Then i think you are left with rolling your own custom configs to build the project the way you want for deployment and development or splitting the file and relocating the client constants.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way we could include this in the angular webpack config. Anyway, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The `angular` team has an aversion to allowing custom configurations in `ng-cli`.